# How can I NOT use the live install on Ubuntu Server 20.04

Tags: system-installation

Is there any method possible to install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS the same as it would have been with 16.04?
Is there a legacy or Debian type menu like there was with Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS?

Comment: Please clarify the question. Provide more details.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the same as it would have been." Package list? Versions? Something else?

Comment: Is this a server installation? and do you mean you want to use the debian installer, now called the legacy installer?

Comment: There is an old style Ubuntu Server iso file at [this link](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-legacy-server/releases/20.04/release/).